# Scala Play route action can't be found

Tags: scala, playframework

I don't  understand why this isn't working.

[image]

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Serve index page from public directory
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
GET     /index                               controllers.FrontendController.index

# An example route (Prefix all API routes with apiPrefix defined in application.conf)
GET     /api/summary                controllers.HomeController.appSummary
POST    /api/getplt/:args                     controllers.UploadController.getPlt(args)# Serve static assets under public directory
GET     /*file                      controllers.FrontendController.assetOrDefault(file)
```

Why can't it resolve the action? I can resolve the /api/summary without problems.

Comment: please show your index method from HomeController

Answer (score 0):

First for your assets use the following:

```
# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
 GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(file)
```

Then you could use the `assetFinder` within your views, something like:

```
<script src="@assetsFinder.path("javascripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is because try to avoid any similar/identical routes, your first route and the asset related route, looks almost the same.

So to answer your question, either the Play is mixing these two routes, or you dont have `index` method within your `HomeController` class.